# Why my SQLite table didn't show in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite

I have a problem in my project, I want to show my existing database of soldiers (id, user_name, phone, password) in a ListView and I failed on it, this Activity crashes.
The logcat shows me that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist". 
EDITED : Question - the _id must be int? or it can be log also?
I will be thankful if you can help me.

```
package com.example.michael.militaryarrangement;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterViewFlipper;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.Cursor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "ListDataActivity";
ListView table;
MySQLiteHelper db;
SoldierDataSource soldierDataSource;
private String[] _allColumns =
        { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PHONE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_data);
    table = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    soldierDataSource = new SoldierDataSource(this);
    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = soldierDataSource.getCursorALL();
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
    showListView();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        createSoldierFromCursor(cursor);
        //cursor.getLong(0);
        //cursor.getString(1);
        //cursor.getString(2);
        //cursor.getString(3);
    }
}

private void populateListView1() {
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

    //get the data and append to a list
    Cursor data  = soldierDataSource.getCursorALL();
    ArrayList<Soldier> SoldiersList = new ArrayList<Soldier>(soldierDataSource.getAllSoldier());
    ArrayList<Soldier> Soldiers = new ArrayList<>();
    //showListView();
    showListView();
    data.moveToFirst();
    //create the list adapter and set the adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SoldiersList);
    //table.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
    table.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String idinsert = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            long id = Long.valueOf(idinsert).longValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + id);
            Cursor data = (Cursor) soldierDataSource.getSoldier(id); //get the id associated with that name
            long soldierID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                soldierID = data.getLong(0);
                data.moveToNext();
            }
            if(soldierID > -1){
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + soldierID);
                Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",soldierID);
                startActivity(editScreenIntent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
            }
        }
    });
}
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private Soldier createSoldierFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {

    Soldier soldier = new Soldier();

    soldier.setMyID(cursor.getLong(0));
    soldier.setMyUsername(cursor.getString(1));
    soldier.setMyPhone(cursor.getString(2));
    soldier.setMyPassword(cursor.getString(3));

    return soldier;

}

private void showListView()
{
    Cursor cursor = soldierDataSource.getCursorALL();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.activity_list_data,
            cursor, //
            _allColumns,
            new int[]{ R.id.soldierid, R.id.username, R.id.phonenum , R.id.password},
            0);
    table.setAdapter(adapter);
    //((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview)).setAdapter(adapter);
}

//

private void populateListViewFromDB() {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) soldierDataSource.getAllSoldier();

    // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
    // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.soldierid,     R.id.username,           R.id.phonenum,     R.id.password};

    // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,       // Context
                    R.layout.activity_list_data,    // Row layout template
                    cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                    _allColumns,            // DB Column names
                    toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
            );

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    ListView table = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    table.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! 'It crashes' is simply not enough information for anyone to provide any help, what error is occurring and being output to the logs?

Comment: Please **stop** adding the [android-studio] tag. The IDE is **irrelevant**.

Comment: rename your DB  and load it with new name.

Comment: It is the solution? @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Comment: Question - the _id must be int? or it can be log also?

Comment: It says `MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,` should be of value `"_id"`

Comment: I tried it , now the listview show me list of 3 buttons (I have 3 Soldiers in my db) replace of sqlite db (the button "show data" , that i used for viewing the data)